# How to restore sentence in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

I have this

```
var input = "([lazy({(jumps{fox([quick(The)]brown)})over}the)]dog)";
```

I want to get

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Any ideas? I tried to use `RegEx` but can not find.

Comment: Is it specific to this case or can the string be anything of varying length?

Comment: Of *course* you can't use a regex, you're going to need to parse that. Does it matter what the grouping symbol used is?

Comment: Sounds like a data structures homework. [Hint: binary expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) and [stacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)).

Comment: If you put your attention in input, you will see that there are some pattern. The first word in deep of brackets. if we remove (The) from  input, the next will [quick] after some iterations, you will get that sentence.

Comment: @arthur I'd start from JS parsing order, for example: consider `quick(The)` as a function call, then the task will open to you.

Comment: But imagine  what if "The" putted in "[]" like "[The]".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to have stack kind of approach with the array here. See the below implementation.

```
var res = "([lazy({(jumps{fox([quick(The)]brown)})over}the)]dog)".split("");
var txt = [],lvl=-1;
res.forEach(function(e,i){
 if(e=='('||e=='{'||e=='['){
  lvl++;
 } else if(e==')'||e=='}'||e==']'){
  lvl--;
 } else {
  if(typeof txt[lvl]=='undefined'){
   txt[lvl] = e;
  } else {
   txt[lvl] = txt[lvl] + e;
  }
 }
});
txt = txt.reverse().join(" ");
console.log(txt);
if(lvl!=-1) { 
  //this will alert if any missing parenthesis
  alert("Pattern error in input"); 
}
```

Edit : updated as per Question owner's description of the pattern in input.

Comment: The whole idea of the task is the parsing order...

Comment: @Teemu JS cannot understand the meaning of words. So, unless there is a pattern in the input, it cannot be done.

Comment: Parentheses you just have removed define the parsing order here, not words.

Comment: please look at input value very attentively, there is  pattern

Comment: @Arthur I have updated the answer. Please check now. (It is better to explain the pattern too in question. In a quick look, most wont get it). :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to perform error checking (hint: remove one of the closing braces and see the result).

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry, but I am not very good at English.

Comment: @OneKitten Assuming this is a homework, I doubt error proof code is provided. The purpose of the task is to get practice of operator precedence and reading order of expressions. It's just a shame, that vivek_nk did it, as OP is the one who's learning here ; ).

Comment: @Teemu Haha.. It still has one gotcha and I leave that to his homework :)